# Canon MP210 printer: cannot install driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bash, package-management, repository, canon

I have tried to add a printer in CUPS, however, there were no **Canon  MP210** drivers. The manufacturer does not provide any LINUX drivers. Also, I tried this on bash:

```
(base)###:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
(base)###:~$ sudo apt update
```

However, I've encountered **errors** like:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And then I **could not** install the driver:

```
(base)###:~$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp210series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mp210series
```

Please give me any suggestions, I have lost hope... Do you think a virtual box (Windows install) would be the best thing to do?

**P.S.**
However, when I had Linux Mint distro everything worked fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Unfortunately, no... Same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **have solved the problem** by installing package **printer-driver-gutenprint.**

This package has the majority of the older printer drivers.

1. Go to the terminal and run the following command:

   ```
    sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint`
   ```
2. Go to the *System Settings* -> *Printers* panel, and remove the printer if it is already configured.
3. Add the printer. You can see the Gutenprint driver is being used after the "Model" label:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you this helped me to use my printer just by the GUI method.

Comment: It works for a Canon MP220 on January 2024.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download this package:

[https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/+files/cnijfilter2_5.90-1+2004+1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/+files/cnijfilter2_5.90-1+2004+1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

Assuming it was downloaded at ~/Downloads

To install it run in a terminal:

```
cd ~/downloads
sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter2_5.90-1+2004+1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Thank you! I did what you told me and, however, the system finds neither MP210 nor MP220 (no MP series at all) drivers. Though I can see that the drivers' list became bigger. Where did you find those deb files? Do you know how to create them? Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: @Linas: Here --- https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/